# Library routines and coroutines

Tags: python, c

I am reading the book "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment"

> This library is important because all contemporary UNIX systems, such as the ones described in this book, provide the **library routines** that are speciﬁed in the C standard.

I am very confused here about the word routine [Coroutine - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine)

Does it has any relations to coroutines?

Comment: To be clear, do you know what routines are? If not, then why are you asking about coroutines? If so, then what specifically in the Wikipedia article is unclear? A quick search for "library routine" [revealed an explanation in the first hit](https://www.computerscience.gcse.guru/theory/library-routine).

Comment: If you want to know about something, try searching for its name. Searching for things with similar names is not necessarily going to help very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

A "routine" is a series of instructions. Similar to a "function" or "program". The word "routine" is somewhat archaic (but "coroutine" is not).

**Library routines** means **library functions**. It has nothing to do with coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

From my understand, coroutine is a specific efficient manipulation way when we handle a routine. the other ways include: multi-process and multi-thread as you may be familiar with.